# How to make one list-item in menu higher than the others with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which has a colored background holder element. I need to make the selected menu-item a little bit higher than its holder, to achieve an affect of overflowing the holder.

```
<div class="menu-holder">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-active">Home</li>
        <li class="menu-item">About us</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Services</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/X5U8p/1/

It looks similar to what I want but the active element looks like overflowing the holder  from the bottom. I would like it to look like it is overflowing from the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<edit>`

to get li active overflowing over top of its parent, you need to set negative margins too :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X5U8p/9/)**

updated CSS from original answer (at bottom):

```
.menu-holder{
    height: 30px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background: #d6d6d6;
}

.menu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-item{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.menu-item-active, .menu-item:hover{
    background: #69265d;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:40px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

end of`</edit>`

---

you can `vertical-align` each `li` to `bottom` and reset `line-height` for the one you wish to grow taller : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X5U8p/6/)**

```
.menu-holder{
    background: #d6d6d6;
    height: 40px;
}

.menu{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu-item{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.menu-item-active{
    background: #69265d;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;/* + padding = 40px height */
    line-height:40px; /* send baseline down , fine if only one line of text*/
}
```

Comment: This one makes the purple and grey areas equally high. I would like to  have the purple area a little higher than the grey one.

Comment: @GladToHelp if you want to keep background-color in ul, then use margins : http://jsfiddle.net/X5U8p/9/

Comment: Margins did the trick. Please edit your answer with that CSS and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a `top` value:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/X5U8p/2/)

```
.menu-item-active{
    background: #69265d;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    top:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that breaks the alignment of the text of the selected item compared to the other items. Is there a way to only increase the height of the selected item, without moving the text vertically?

Comment: @GladToHelp - theres a few CSS tricks you can use: http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/X5U8p/7/

Comment: Nice trick but it's rather visual only. If I hover the mouse over the white area above the unselected items, I get a hand cursor.

Comment: @GladToHelp so you can add `cursor:default;` to the `.menu-item-active`